# Is it possible to use two controller classes with one URI in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, controller, uri

I m working on this project where am I trying to access two different controllers with the same URI. After trying to run it I m getting a BeanCreationException. 
So it happens that I m getting an Error while creating a bean. 
I hope there is a way to deal with this.

The error message that I m getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map
>   'userController' method  public java.lang.String
>   com.javalanguagezone.interviewtwitter.controller.UserController.overview(java.security.Principal,org.springframework.ui.Model)
>   to {[/overview],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'tweetController'
>   bean method

I m using as well Thymleaf for this project. The URI that I m for those two controllers: http://localhost:8080/api/overview.The two controllers are providing my Thymleaf page with information that i have to present at the same time with the URI just mentioned. With this, I m calling both controllers but I m getting a previously mentioned error.

The first controller class(TweetController):

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class TweetController {

private TweetService tweetService;

public TweetController(TweetService tweetService) {
this.tweetService = tweetService;
}
@GetMapping( "/overview")
public String tweetsFromUser(Principal principal, Model model) {

model.addAttribute("tweets",tweetService.tweetsFromUser(principal).size());
return "api/index";

}
}
```

The second controller class is:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

private UserService userService;

public UserController(UserService userService) {
 this.userService = userService;
 }

@GetMapping("/followers")
public String followers(Principal principal) {
userService.getUsersFollowers(principal);
return "api/index";
}

@GetMapping("/following")
public int following(Principal principal) {
return userService.getUsersFollowing(principal);
}

@GetMapping("/overview")
public String overview(Principal principal, Model model){

model.addAttribute("followers",userService.getUsersFollowers(principal));
model.addAttribute("following",userService.getUsersFollowing(principal));
return "api/index";
}    }
```

**My question**: is there a way a fix it or I to look for another way around? I m relatively a newbie with Spring. Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: You can’t call two same mapping controller from the same uri.that’s why you are getting ambiguous mapping.you should change the endpoint for both controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to REST conventions, you should not have /overview, but /user/overview. You can set it by supplying @RequestMapping("/user") in your userController.

In the same way you would have "/tweet/overview" endpoint.

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/tweet")
public class TweetController {
```

doing it any other way is against conventions, against Spring Rules and probably means you're doing something wrong. Spring does not allow two methods with same uri because it does not know which method exactly you would want to call.

upd: if you need logic, you can send parameters to GET: /overview?customParam=user

```
@GetMapping( "/overview")
public String tweetsFromUser(@RequestParam(value="customParam") String 
param, Principal principal, Model model) {
// logic checking customParam...
```

But that CANNOT be in two different controllers. The only way to specify the controller, is through base-uri and parameters are not part of it.

Spring determines the method by 2 parameters: Mapping and HTTP method. There is no way, unless you modify Spring manually, to allow 3rd parameter in this case. Also, there is no 3rd parameter.

Alternatively, you can have 3rd controller with Mapping, that calls other 2 controllers when "/overview" endpoint is triggered. In that case, you need to remove the mapping from tweet and user - controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but now I have to have two different URIs to call the Controller classes or not? I mean i need two different things from the controllers by using just one URI. Is there a way around it ?

Comment: If I asked you to bring single apple, and there are two in the basket: one is gold, one is green, would you know which one? Unless you specify which one, you can't :)

Comment: Thank you again for clearing me up.  So it would work then if i would create an Instance of the TweetService inside of my UserController and then call the methods from the TweetService class as well with of course the UserService methods.

Comment: in the case you want to merge them, you better have separate controller. Like, GeneralController, for methods like that. I say it, because if you do need to do it, there is a problem in design. I don't know why you can't use /user/overview endpoint, but it's a problem to design

Comment: I see, I will do it with merging, cause it is more clearly and then with one endpoint i will get the services from TweetService and UserService.

Comment: @JasminMerusic a little update on the post: you might create 3rd controller and remove annotations from first two, while simply redirecting calls to appropriate controller based on additional parameters :)